# Position Fail with jQuery cycle carousel children

Tags: jquery, carousel, cycle, jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

I want to make an news cycle using the [jQuery plugin cycle2 with its "carousel transition"](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php). It works already fine but there is one problem I need to fix. If the news items have not the same height, the container gets the height of the biggest child and the others were placed to the bottom of the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/zd8sH/

```
var cycleOpts = {
'fx' : 'carousel',
'slides' : '> li',
'carousel-visible' : 2,
'manual-trump' : false,
'manualTrump' : false,
'autoHeight' : 'calc' };
```

Thanks! 
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else comes across this issue, here is the answer...

```
autoHeight: 'container'
```